# Xcode 11 crashes when running Unit Tests in parallel for framework project

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, frameworks

The first test will start up and about half a second later Xcode will lock up instead of starting another test. About 30 seconds after that, Xcode crashes and I get the following crash log (see below).

- This started happening after I upgraded to Xcode 11.
- If I run unit tests in serial it works just fine.
- Strangely it seems to only happen on my 2018 Macbook Pro. On other Macbooks and Mac Minis the unit tests are able to run tests in parallel without the crash.
- It only happens with the unit tests. I can run the UI tests for my project in parallel.
- I have another framework-based project on the same machine that is experiencing the same issue.
- I've tried deleting and re-installing Xcode several times.
- Edit: I just now tried wiping the hard drive of the Macbook and reinstalling Mac OS. The issue persists.

```
Process:               Xcode [823]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               11.0 (14936)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14936000000000000~3
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       832762837
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [823]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-09-23 16:39:38.684 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.6 (16P6571)
Anonymous UUID:        BC74C3A5-0B03-9716-16C5-8C448AD75627


Time Awake Since Boot: 1600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        27

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11A420a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-14899/DVTFoundation/Multicore/DVTFuture.mm:376
Details:  Attempted to transition to the failed state, but did not provide an error.
<DVTFuture 0x7fc173624f60 Running>
    Progress:    Initial
    Result:      (null)
    Error:       (null)
    Started at:    0   -[DVTFuture init] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[DVTFuture initWithBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  2   +[DVTFuture futureWithBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:] (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
  4   __55-[IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher performWorkerAction]_block_invoke (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
  5   __43-[DVTDispatchLock asyncPerformLockedBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
  7   __DVTDispatchBarrierAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  8   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   _dispatch_lane_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _dispatch_lane_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 14   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

    Finished at: (null)
Object:   <DVTFuture: 0x7fc173624f60>
Method:   -_internalSetState:result:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc17336ae40>{number = 81, name = (null)}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[DVTFuture _internalSetState:result:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4   __35-[DVTFuture setState:result:error:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   invocation function for block in decltype(fp0()) DVTDispatchLockPerformLockedWriterBlock<void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong>(DVTDispatchLock*, void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong) (in DVTFoundation)
  6   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10   decltype(fp0()) DVTDispatchLockPerformLockedWriterBlock<void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong>(DVTDispatchLock*, void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong) (in DVTFoundation)
 11   -[DVTFuture setState:result:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 12   -[DVTFuture failWithError:] (in DVTFoundation)
 13   __68-[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 14   -[DVTFuture initWithBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 15   +[DVTFuture futureWithBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 16   -[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:] (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 17   __55-[IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher performWorkerAction]_block_invoke (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 18   __43-[DVTDispatchLock asyncPerformLockedBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 19   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 20   __DVTDispatchBarrierAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 21   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 22   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 23   _dispatch_lane_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 24   _dispatch_lane_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 25   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (in libdispatch.dylib)
 26   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 27   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error code appears to be referencing the lack of a parent process, denoted by the question marks and the either return code `[1]` or that that PID is responsible for that function. Is there possibly a problem with DVTFramework? If the problem persists, I recommend contacting Apple.

**Edit**

Yes there appears to be a problem with DVT as shown by the error hint:

````
Method:   -_internalSetState:result:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc17336ae40>{number = 81, name = (null)}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[DVTFuture _internalSetState:result:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4   __35-[DVTFuture setState:result:error:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   invocation function for block in decltype(fp0()) DVTDispatchLockPerformLockedWriterBlock<void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong>(DVTDispatchLock*, void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong) (in DVTFoundation)
  6   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10   decltype(fp0()) DVTDispatchLockPerformLockedWriterBlock<void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong>(DVTDispatchLock*, void () block_pointer () block_pointer __strong) (in DVTFoundation)
 11   -[DVTFuture setState:result:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 12   -[DVTFuture failWithError:] (in DVTFoundation)
 13   __68-[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 14   -[DVTFuture initWithBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 15   +[DVTFuture futureWithBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 16   -[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:] (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 17   __55-[IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher performWorkerAction]_block_invoke (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 18   __43-[DVTDispatchLock asyncPerformLockedBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 19   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 20   __DVTDispatchBarrierAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 21   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 22   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 23   _dispatch_lane_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 24   _dispatch_lane_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 25   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (in libdispatch.dylib)
 26   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 27   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)```
````

Comment: Agreed, I figure it's an issue with the DVT library. Sadly the only thing that comes up when I google it is "disconnect the device and re-connect it" which can't be done with a simulator. I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve waiting for Apple to fix something on their end.

Comment: Try to find an Apple store near you and ask them about it. They might be able to manually reinstall and restart the DVT lib service. Other than that, I don't see much you can do. Edit: Or fill out a help request on their website.

Comment: Sorry, wish there was more the community could do to fix Apple products, but as an owner, I'm sure you're well aware of the propriety and selectiveness of their certifications.